# Java - Getting location (latitude, longitude) of a mailing address without communication over internet

Tags: java, geolocation, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have mailing addresses and need to convert them to coordinates (latitude, longitude) through a java program. The trouble is the program is not allowed to communicate over internet (probably due to privacy issues). I searched, and all I found are programs that make a call to Google map or other services, thus they all use internet. Any body knows anyway to achieve this through some code without internet? Any Java code that may use some libs or frameworks?

If nothing is available in Java, then I can be open to other languages. I am reading about postgis now (suggested by a colleague). Not sure if it works, but if you know about this, please give some advice/code, etc.

**Note based on the commnent: If a DBMS knows how to convert an address to coordinates, then that works too because I can install the DBMS locally. Not sure if PostGis can do this**

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean, how do you get a database with all the information that you can put on your hard drive?

Comment: yeah, if the database itself knows how to convert an address to geo-coordinates.

Comment: and I think a database is likely needed because it seems that there is no single algorithm or library can achieve this.

Comment: Keep a local database of street information for look up doesn't make sense to me, not to mention of where to get this data, and technically on the lookup and the size of itself. Perhaps, you should consider the lookup using city level.

Answer (score 0):

Mailing address(house number, street, town) databases, with coordinates, can be obtained for many countries commercially but tend to be expensive. ZIP Postal code databases are more readily available and can be relatively cheap or free. Most databases can handle searches by distance , including PostGis.

Comment: Can you please clarify, if PostGis can take an address and convert it to coordinates? And possibly, how, in case you know? Thanks

Comment: NO PostGis nor any other database can convert an address to coordinates. Databases can only store coordinates and manipulate the data. Ie you can count how many "things" are in a postcode, the nearest "thing" to a certain coordinate etc. You either have to create your own database or obtain one from a third party.